# C# (winforms) text file in DataGridView (substring )

Tags: c#

How can I pass substring or a single character within the datagridview.

this is my text file

```
qwqwqw
a000v00   5000x222w000
BB00fFF   444422555550
qwqwqw
```

i want to show this content in DataGridView in below format

```
1      2     3       4     
a000   v00   5000x   222w000
BB00   fFF   44442   2555550
```

This is my error code
How should I do ?

```
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("1", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("2", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("3", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("4", typeof(string));
            string path;
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            ofd.Title = "txt";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.Cancel) return;
            path = ofd.FileName;   

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            string[] values;
            for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length-1; i++)     
            {

                values = lines[i].Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                string[] row = new string[values.Length];

                for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
                {
                    row[j] = values[j].Trim();
                }
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView.DataSource = table;
        }
```

Thank you very much

Comment: are you saking how to get the data from `DataTable table` to show up in a `DataGridView` ? are you using winforms?

Comment: YSE，Windows Forms

Comment: SORRY，Not referring to this problem

Comment: Solution to the problem, such as the 1F  answer.
My english expression is not good.
Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your split appears to only split into two items as only one space.  Also you seem to be ignoring lines without a space separator.

If so, try chaning the code that parses the text line and creates the datatable to something like this:

```
        for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)
        {

            values = lines[i].Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (values.Length == 2)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                row[0] = values[0].Substring(0, 4);
                row[1] = values[0].Substring(4).Trim();
                row[2] = values[1].Substring(0, 5);
                row[3] = values[1].Substring(5).Trim();
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
```

and make sure the table datasource of the datagridview.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will learn this part of the logic well